# How to retrieve currency exchange rates in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a function that retrieves the currency rates in Excel?

For example if a cell has a value of 10$ and I want to change this into another currency that is valid at the moment.

Comment: See:   http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Currency-Converter-With-Microsoft-Excel

Answer (score 0):

There is a step-by-step solution:

https://eves.genia.berlin/excelquery_e.html

Call the URL http://genia.berlin/usd.php to get the actual exchange rate in comparison to US-Dollar. The accuracy is 4 decimal places. An erroneous call returns an empty result, no error message. One parameter given in [ISO 4217](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) notation, e.g.: http://genia.berlin/usd.php?eur